# What does ても mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

I am having trouble translating this sentence because of `ても`.

> そんなにゲームばかりして、目が悪くなっ**ても**知らないわよ。

Does it mean:

> If you only play the game so much, your eyes will get bad *even if* you don't know.

I am not sure if that translation makes sense or is correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 「そんなにゲームばかりして、目が悪くなっ**ても**知らないわよ。」

And your TL is:

> "If you play so many games, your eyes will get bad even if ***you don't know***."

The part that you mistranslated, interestingly, is not even the "ても" part ("even if").  Rather it was the unmentioned subject of the verb 「知らない」.

It is the speaker who 知らない, not the game-player she is talking to.  (I am envisioning a female speaker because of the わよ-ending.)

This 知らない, though ***very*** often used, is hard to translate, too.  It does ***not*** mean "I do not know.".  It is more like "***Don't say I didn't tell you!***" or "I won't be responsible (for that)!"

"***You just keep playing games; Don't say I didn't tell you (not to) if your eyes went bad***!"

Comment: Someone should mention this, but the another important cause of misunderstanding *is* in the "ても" part. "AてもB" means "B even if A", but OP's translation is "A even if B".